# Synonym for amnesiac and incognito

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The question '[Is it dangerous to use Tails without persistent entry guards?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/636/88)' has the two tags [amnesiac](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesiac) and [incognito](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incognito). I would suggest to make both a synonym for [tails](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tails). What do you think about?

Answer (score 2):

No, incognito and amnesic are general terms.

- Any live DVD is amnesic by definition: when you power down and contents of RAM disappeared, everything is gone.
- There are other Tor centric operating systems which would also be incognito by definition.

Just we because Tails is incognito and amnesic, we shouldn't kill those general terms.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the tags aren't necessarily synonymous with Tails. Both are a part of tails, but it's not certain that all incognito or amnesiac systems refer only to tails.

I'm certainly not denying the synonym outright, other mods or community members may disagree. I am also open to being persuaded on the question.